# PHP Elasticsearch GET value of a field from all documents in index

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I've an Elasticsearch with an index where all documents have the same fields. One of these fields is called "Company".

I want to create a PHP script that runs a query that gets the value of that field from all the documents in that index.

How could I go about doing this? I'm using Elasticsearch 6.3 and PHP 7.2.

This does not work but should help in understanding what I'm trying to do:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'aksjeregisteret2017',
    'type' => '_doc',
    'field' => ['Company']
];

$response = $es->get($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ole
Are you trying to query only the field 'Company'?If so just use '_source' instead of 'field' .
So your

```
 $params = [
    'index' => 'aksjeregisteret2017',
    'type' => '_doc',

];
$params['body']['_source' ]= 'Company';
$params['body']['query']['match_all']['boost'] = 1.2;
$response = $es->search($params);
```

Reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html